# Add leading numbers to Numbers in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

have a df

```
a         b

mark     50

john     60

jack     30

harry     80

jacob     10
```

Need to add new values here it is (141) to b column, type of b columns is `numpy.int64`  into the df like this

```
a         b

mark     14150

john     14160

jack     14130

harry     14180

jacob     14110
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, simpliest is add `14100` if all values has length 2:

```
df.b = df.b + 14100
```

Or for general solution use:

```
df.b = ('141' + df.b.astype(str)).astype(int)
print (df)
       a      b
0   mark  14150
1   john  14160
2   jack  14130
3  harry  14180
4  jacob  14110
```